# Laravel real time with socket.io

Tags: laravel, redis, socket.io

I am experimenting real time app using Laravel and socket.io. I make a seperate node and redis server. Now I see several tutorials introducing redis to subscribe to channels. But I try without redis and socket.io is able to connect and emit etc.

The question is, what is redis used for and are there any specific scenarios that redis is able to handle that socket.io can't?

Thank you.

Comment: I would recommend Pusher and Vue.js

Comment: Ready my question again.

Comment: Redis can be used for real time notifications, it acts as a database of sorts. But it's more complicated to use, that's why I recommended Pusher.

Comment: I have used pusher in the past. I have limitations in budget, thats is why I have curiosity for socket.io

Comment: Pusher is free unless you have a massive-scale app

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Socket IO helps in communicating between two different browser tabs, and that do not have anything to do with Laravel application only using **socket.js** file. So when you want to communicate between Laravel application and browser like chat or real time notifications about the events that happen in laravel application, then Redis will help you.

Laravel application send the data to Redis and Redis pass data to socket IO, then socket IO sends data to browser.

This is similar to AJAX, but in ajax the client ask for data and server/ laravel application responds to the AJAX request.

In our case the server it self can send updated data, as the change happens with out browser requesting, so this is helpful because the browser does not when the data is updated on the server side.

When I started learning socket IO and Redis I struggled a lot to find and understand this, hope this helps you.

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much. I guess we have to start somewhere :)

Comment: I am also able to receive and broascast data without redis, just the socket.io itself. What are specific scenarios redis is helpful for?

Comment: With Socket IO you are communicating between browsers, your laravel server(MySQL or what ever) is not part of that communication. You are using only Socket IO server for this specific broadcasts. All the other implementation of Laravel application is done with your Laravel server(MySQL). You use Redis to involve Laravel server in this Socket IO broadcasting.